# What does it mean when backbutton has to be pressed many times for an activity to close on android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-broadcast, android-intentservice

I have an activity that only closes after I press back button of hardware many times (more or less 2 times).

I have tried detecting when this is happening and I think this must be due to an IntentService I'm using that uses broadcastReceiver to receive back some info, but I'm not really sure since no error message or warning are being displayed.

Does anyone with more experience has an idea what does it usually mean that I have to press many times backbutton in activity in order for it to close?

I even tried overriding onBackPressed() but it's not working:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

## UPDATE

So I inserted some console logs onCreate() and onDestroy() of activity so it seems that once on activity when I press back button the activity seems to be created again (onCreate() of activity is called again) and then onDestroy is called.

## UPDATE 2

This is the method I think might be triggering the problem:

```
  private void startRestaurantsModelService(String url) {

        if(restaurantsBroadcastReceiver == null){
            //Intent to use RestaurantModel to getRestaurantsJsonArrays
            Intent getRestaurants = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, RestaurantModel.class);
            getRestaurants.putExtra("urlRestaurants", url);
            startService(getRestaurants);

            //The receiver that will receive restaurants list from RestaurantModel IntentService
            restaurantsBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    Bundle restaurantsBundle = intent.getExtras();
                    //Assign Restaurants received from service
                    restaurants = (List<Restaurant>) restaurantsBundle.getSerializable("restaurantsList");

                    //Now that we have restaurants list configure the RecyclerView
                    recyclerViewConfiguration();

                    //We need to know number of open restaurants so we can use different layout settings
                    //for closed restaurants in adapter using getItemViewType()
                    numberOfOpenRestaurants = restaurantsBundle.getInt("numberOfOpenRestaurants");
                    restaurantAdapter.setNumberOfOpenRestaurants(numberOfOpenRestaurants);
                    //Then update the RecyclerView
                    updateRecyclerView();

                    if (loadingDialog.isShowing()) {
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();

                    }

                }
            };

            registerReceiver(restaurantsBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(RestaurantModel.BROADCAST_ACTION));
        }
    }
```

I'm unregistering that broadcast in onPause:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    try {
        unregisterReceiver(restaurantsBroadcastReceiver);
        restaurantsBroadcastReceiver = null;


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any fragment transactions in back stack?

Comment: it usually means you either have stuff on the fragment backstack, or you have several activities, possibly identical, stacked on top of each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for guidance!!!

## Solved it

Inside my `startRestaurantsModelService()` I havemethod `recyclerViewConfiguration()` which calls `recyclerViewOnClickListener()`

It seems this method was causing the mistake, because I was setting two times the clicklistener:

```
 @Override
    public void recyclerViewOnClickListener() {
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this,
                        new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                                if (restaurants.get(position).isOpen()) {
                                    Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);

                                    i.putExtra("restaurant", restaurants.get(position));
                                    i.putExtra("userAddress", address);

                                    startActivity(i);

                                }

                            }
                        })
        );
    }
```

So I was setting 2 click listeners on the same recyclerview so now I made a boolean to check if recyclerview already had a clicklistener if not I set it if true then I don't set it again.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to ensure that onBackPressed() is not overriden in your Activity.

Comment: Well, my second guess is that you might have more than one instance of the Activity already running by the time you're trying to press back. You think this might be the case?

Comment: Is there anyway to check if there is more than one instance of the activity running?

Comment: adb shell dumpsys activity shall be helpful.

Comment: are you setting any flags to your activities? I also think it is more than one instance of the Activity

Comment: @n.m. ill try making a console log on Activities onCreate()